# how to share data from multiple js files in es6?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to make a game in ES6. I already have made multiple files. A main file where i gather all the information from the different objects, a file where i am going to make a character and a file that has the canvas properties.

the problem is:
The file walter.es6 has a square that is going to move from the left to right.
So i start the draw(); of walter.es6 in the script.es6 (the main file). But the walter.es6 file needs the ctx from the canvas.es6 file.

I think it's because, walter.es6 doesn't know that canvas.es6 exists. But to keep the code clean, it's not necessary that they know each other (that's what was told me before). there needs to be another solution so that walter.es6 knows what ctx mains.. but how?

I hope someone can help me.
Thank you in advance.

Here are the files i've been talking about:

**script.es6**

```
    const WalterPlayer = require('./walter.es6')
    const DeaEnemy = require('./dea.es6')
    const Wereld = require('./level.es6')
    const Canvas = require('./canvas.es6')


    class Hoofdclass {
        constructor() {
            this.walter = new WalterPlayer();
            this.enemy = new DeaEnemy();
            this.wereld = new Wereld();
            this.canvas = new Canvas();
            this.draw();
        }
        draw(){
            this.walter.draw();

            //alles in beweging zetten
            window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw.bind(this));
    }
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        let t = new Hoofdclass();
    });
```

**walter.es6**

```
class Walter {
    constructor() {
        this.x = 250;
        this.y = 200;
        this.height = 10;
        this.width = 10;
        console.log(this.canvas)
    }
    draw(){
         this.ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,400)
         this.ctx.beginPath();
         this.x += 1;
         this.y += 0.25;
         this.ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.height, this.width);
         this.ctx.closePath();
    }
}

module.exports = Walter;
```

**canvas.es6**

```
class Canvas {
    constructor(c, ctx) {
        this.c = document.getElementById("canvas");
        this.ctx = this.c.getContext("2d");
        console.log("pieppiep")
    }
}

module.exports = Canvas;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the needed object to the objects that require it. Either on instantiation, or as needed.

As needed eg

```
this.walter.draw(this.canvas.ctx); // in draw loop
```

and in walter.

```
draw(ctx){
     ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,400);
     ... etc
```

Or instantiation

```
this.walter = new WalterPlayer(this.canvas.ctx); // instantiation
```

and in the constructor

```
class Walter {
    constructor(ctx) {
         this.ctx = ctx;
```

Obviously you need to create Walter after the canvas.

Or the very lazy way is to make the objects you want to share global (Though some may say don't, that will depend on the context you are planning to run in and the performance needs of the app).